# Run Oracle SQL with different terminator than default

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have an oracle script to be run that I received from a vendor. Looking at the SQL, however, the terminator is not a default `;` or `/`.

```
create table TableA
(
   Column1 raw(16) not null,
   Column2 blob not null,
   Column3 not null
)$$
```

How do I change the terminators to `$$` ?

Edit: I am trying to run this SQL file in SQLPlus.

Comment: If this is plsql, start with

Comment: You can `set sqlterminator $`, but that only accepts a single character, so you can't set it to `$$` in SQL\*Plus. Can you use any other client? Or modify the file first, to replace all `$$` with `;`?

Answer (score -2):

In pl/sql start with

```
Delimiter $$
```

followed by your create.

Comment: I edited the question. I am looking to run the SQL files in SQLPlus.